# bash or python command to cycle through terminals and execute commands on them?

Tags: python, bash, terminal

Stating the problem in a simplified form:
I'm ssh'ing to two servers using two bash terminals and running programs on the servers whose outputs I need to continuously view. Server1's output appears on terminal1 and Server2's output on terminal2.

Is there a way to run a script which is aware of how many terminals are open, and be able to cycle through them and execute bash commands on them?

Pseudocode:

```
open terminal1
run program1
open terminal2
run program2
switch to terminal1
run program3 on terminal1
```

Looked at the man page for xterm, but there was no option to switch between terminals.
The closest I could get was [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1055429) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436899/how-do-i-start-commands-in-new-terminals-in-bash-script). But both didn't help.

Comment: Thought I'd also link to another useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436899/how-do-i-start-commands-in-new-terminals-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)

Comment: Solution is intended to use `python` .

Comment: Or bash.  It's not language specific so I broadened the scope of available tools.  Screen is an excellent options here.

Comment: Ah, I see, misunderstood, sorry.  Didn't see the other answer was you.  Rock on.

Comment: Thanks, but to switch between screens, I had to use the Ctrl+a keys. I wanted a way to do it with a script.

Comment: Screen can be scripted with the `-X` option: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen

Comment: cool! Did some more searching and found that this is what you meant "screen -X select 2" (where '2' is screen number 2). Thank you so much!!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [5]: import subprocess

In [6]: import shlex

In [7]: subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls; read -n1"'))
Out[7]: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x9480a2c>
```

Comment: Erm...I'm new to scripting in Python and bash. Python didn't recognize the "In [5]" etc. So couldn't understand what your code does. Help?

Comment: It is copied directly from a python prompt (not the standard one, SciPy?). The "In [5]" etc are not part of the script.

Comment: How does one switch between terminals? I tried storing the return value of subprocess.Popen in a variable to access the shell it opens, but I kept getting syntax errors for everything I tried.

Comment: @Nav: you need to use subprocess.communicate() and subprocess.Popen() effectively , you can't switch terminal but you can pass message between two process which will be performing two different task and If your concern is to just get the output use subprocess.getoutput()

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `screen` would be [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). Once you split your screens as you need them you can send commands to either one from a separate terminal something like:

```
tmux send-keys -t sessionname:0.0 "ls -al" "Enter"
tmux send-keys -t sessionname:0.1 "ls -al" "Enter"
```

The `-t` option references "sessionname":"window number"."pane number". I believe you can do a similar thing with `screen` but I've never used it.

Another option you might consider, if having two separate screens is not highly pertinent, is the python utility [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.0/index.html). You can script commands to multiple servers and fetch results.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `bash` script that runs `screen` was the solution for me in a similar case.
You can use `screen` to create a screen session, and inside, create multiple numbered windows, and execute commands on them.

I am running a scrip on a cluster with 8 computers, so I `ssh` in each of them and run the command `htop` to check if no one is using.

The flag `-S` names a session on screen, `-p` enumerates the session window, and `-X stuff` runs a command. Note that in order to run a command `"` is needed on a new line to simulate carriage return(Enter)

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m -S dracos
# window 0 is created by default, command ssh is executed " needed in new line to simulate pressing Enter
screen -S dracos -p 0 -X stuff "ssh draco1
"
screen -S dracos -p 0 -X stuff "htop
"
for n in {2..8}; do
  # create now window using `screen` command
  screen -S dracos -X screen $n
  #ssh to each draco
  screen -S dracos -p $n -X stuff "ssh draco$n
"
  #run htop in each draco
 screen -S dracos -p $n -X stuff "htop
"
screen -S dracos -p $n -X stuff "<your_new_command_here>
"
done
```

If you want to run commands in other order you can put the line bellow after the `for`

```
screen -S dracos -p $n -X stuff "<your_new_command_here>
```