# How can I start a shell script in the terminal, using a shell script command?

Tags: bash

I'd like to write a shell script that starts running another shell script in a separate terminal window. Which command should I use to run the following shell script in the terminal?

```
#!/bin/sh
#name of this script: install applications.sh
sudo apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
sudo apt-get install docky -y
#etc.
```

Comment: I'm attempting to write a shell script that will launch this shell script in a new terminal window.

Comment: You know that terminal emulators are commands too, right?

Comment: No, I don't. Which terminal emulators are commands?

Comment: Here's some additional relevant information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436899/how-do-i-start-commands-in-new-terminals-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the terminal emulator your want to launch. Here are two examples:

```
xterm -e 'bash applications.sh'
gnome-terminal -e 'bash applications.sh'
```

Comment: Sloppy today, missed the 'in a separate terminal window' part in my hopefully-soon-deleted answer. But instead of 'bash', consider '$SHELL'.

Comment: Is "$SHELL" a separate scripting language? I'm not familiar with that language.

Comment: @JonasN I chose `bash` because it matches the `bash` tag on the question. Really, the script should be marked executable and let the shebang handle it (which happens to not be bash in his example).

Comment: @AndersonGreen $SHELL is an environment variable containing the name of your user's login shell.

Comment: To clarify, @jordanm is right in it being a good idea for scripts to declare what language they are written in, and not try to force any other interpretation on them. The SHELL variable should be used when a new CLI is opened, so a user gets his favorite shell. (SHELL can be set in a init script or otherwise.) Hope this 'undoes' my stupid comment above.