# how to open a gnome terminal to execute a command with gnome-terminal, constantly?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I have a sh file which includes those lines:

```
gnome-terminal\
  --tab\
    --title="ElasticSearch"\
    --working-directory="/home/username/program/bin"\
    -e "bash -c './somecommand'"\
```

when I run it, a gnome terminal will open and run a command for me. The  problem is, when I press ctrl+c to stop the running command, the terminal closed. Is there a way to stop the running command and keep the terminal alive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436899/how-do-i-start-commands-in-new-terminals-in-bash-script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your command works fine but the `gnome-terminal` closes after the `somecommand` terminates, the reason being `gnome-terminal` not running the `bash` as it's default shell.

To get the bash prompt(`$`) after the command command completes, you need to trigger it back.

```
-e "bash -c ./somecommand;bash"\
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I kill said command with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then it closes the whole tab.

Comment: Space (or the lack of one) around that ; is important.  If somecommand has arguments you may need to quote your command.  for example -e "bash -c ipython --pylab;bash"  does not work but -e "bash -c 'ipython -i --pylab myscript.py';bash" did the trick

Answer (score 13):

`-e` has since been deprecated. Use `gnome-terminal -- somecommand` now.