# Bash: Execute command WITH ARGUMENTS in new terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, command, arguments, quoting

So i want to open a new terminal in bash and execute a command with arguments.
As long as I only take something like `ls` as command it works fine, but when I take something like `route -n` , so a command with arguments, it doesnt work.
The code:

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -e whoami`  #WORKS

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -e route -n` #DOESNT WORK

I already tried putting "" around the command and all that but it still doesnt work

Comment: See: [how to open a gnome terminal to execute a command with gnome-terminal, constantly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38135995/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -e 'bash -c "route -n; read"'
```

The final `read` prevents the window from closing after execution of the previous commands. It will close when you press a key.

If you want to experience headaches, you can try with more quote nesting:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash \
  -e 'bash -c "route -n; read -p '"'Press a key...'"'"'
```

(In the following examples there is no final `read`. Let’s suppose we fixed that in the profile.)

If you want to print an empty line and enjoy multi-level escaping too:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash \
  -e 'bash -c "printf \\\\n; route -n"'
```

The same, with another quoting style:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash \
  -e 'bash -c '\''printf "\n"; route -n'\'
```

Variables are expanded in double quotes, not single quotes, so if you want them expanded you need to ensure that the outermost quotes are double:

```
command='printf "\n"; route -n'
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash \
  -e "bash -c '$command'"
```

Quoting can become really complex. When you need something more advanced that a simple couple of commands, it is advisable to write an independent shell script with all the readable, parametrized code you need, save it somewhere, say `/home/user/bin/mycommand`, and then invoke it simply as

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -e /home/user/bin/mycommand
```

Comment: Awesome bro, that works :D Btw I defined in the profile that it doesnt close, so i dont need read but nice to see that it would work like that too. And only one question: How could I integrate `printf  "\n"` in the code so basically I want that it prints an empty line before it executes the other command, i tried writing it in front of `route -n` but it does nothing.

Comment: Edited with `printf \\\\n` as you requested... Quotes and escapes tend to multiply out of control...

Comment: And how can I add variables to it so something like  `command="route -n"`   ... 'bash -c "$command"' (<- That doesnt work) (Sry thats my first bash script xD)

Comment: Edited again. :)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH BRO!!! You cant believe how much you helped me :D  And I always use double quotes so thats just perfect for me :D And thanks for writing the file-version here again although I already knew that but my commands are too simple for that. Thanks again <3

Comment: Showing how to use `printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"` to generate a string that, when run (with `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c $cmd_q"`) will invoke that command would probably be a helpful extension to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new terminal with a command using the following:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -- \
    bash -c "<command>"
```

To continue the terminal with the normal bash profile, add `exec bash`:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -- \
    bash -c "<command>; exec bash"
```

Here's how to create a [Here document](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents) and pass it as the command:

```
cmd="$(printf '%s\n' 'wc -w <<-EOF
  First line of Here document.
  Second line.
  The output of this command will be '15'.
EOF' 'exec bash')"

xterm -e bash -c "${cmd}"
```

To open a new terminal and run an initial command with a script, add the following in a script:

```
nohup xterm -e bash -c "$(printf '%s\nexec bash' "$*")" &>/dev/null &
```

*When [`$*`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is quoted, it expands the arguments to a single word, with each separated by the first character of IFS. `nohup` and `&>/dev/null &` are used only to allow the terminal to run in the background.*

Comment: `echo "${cmd}"` is not very portable. Keep in mind that the `$(...)` expansion is run with the current shell, *not* with bash, so you don't know whose implementation of `echo` it is. See [the POSIX spec for `echo`]( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to get  an idea of just how uncertain/unreliable its behavior can be.

Comment: `echo "${@}"` is particularly unreliable. You can't tell the difference between `echo "hello" "world"` and `echo "hello world"`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: *If* you're guaranteed that your exterior shell is bash or ksh, much better to use `printf '%q ' "$@"` to form a properly quoted command (`printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"` if it's known to be bash; ksh optimizes `cmd=$(printf '%q ' "$@")` to avoid forking an actual subshell, but bash does not).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. This was in fact only tested in bash. I will test your solution with different shells and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd suggest something like `printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world"` as the command under test so quoting/string-splitting issues are detected.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I did not know that echo was not very portable. It seems like a common mistake among novice Linux users. Several months ago, I could not get the Here document to work as the command with echo using anything other than "$(echo "${@}"; printf '\n exec bash')" with xterm. Your solution works and is better as it is portable and does not create a subshell so I will use it in the answer instead. Changed `cmd="wc -w <<-EOF ...` to `printf -v cmd '%s\n ' "wc -w <<-EOF ...`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `printf -v cmd ...` is a bashism -- so while it's faster to execute  than `cmd=$(printf ...)` on bash, if portability is a goal, you might need to consider the latter.

Comment: BTW, I very sincerely doubt that `bash -c "$@"` or `bash -c "${@}"` does what you intend. Only `"$1"` is passed in the `-c` position; `$2` and onward are passed later, becoming `$0`, `$1`, etc. when running the script in the first position.

Comment: To demonstrate with the test command I gave earlier, `set -- printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world"` to assign each word of that command to a different argument position, and then run `xterm -e bash -c "${@}; sleep 30"`.

Comment: ...by contrast, *with bash or ksh*, `set -- printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world"; cmd=$(printf '%q ' "$@"); xterm -e bash -c "$cmd; sleep 30"` actually Does The Right Thing.

Comment: By the way, if you want to make your test case even more pathological, consider `set -- printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" '$(touch /tmp/insecure)' "goodbye world"`, and look at whether `/tmp/insecure` exists after each round of testing.

Comment: Changed `printf -v cmd '%s\n ' "wc -w <<-EOF...` to `cmd="$(printf '%s\n ' 'wc -w <<-EOF...`. As for `set -- printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world"; cmd=$(printf '%q ' "$@"); xterm -e bash -c "$cmd; sleep 30"`, it works, escaping the "*" as expected, however, not when arguments are passed rather than set, as `%q` causes everything to get escaped. How can `printf` be used when the arguments are passed?

Comment: eh? `yourfunc() { set -- printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world"; ...; }` is **exactly** the same as `yourfunc() { ...; }` invoked as `yourfunc printf '%s\n' "hello world" "*" "goodbye world" `. You'll need to provide a test case where this isn't true for me to grok where you're coming from.

Comment: I meant when passing just `"hello world" "*" "goodbye world"`.

Comment: I think we're not entirely on the same page though. Passing `"hello world" "*" "goodbye world"` on its own works, however, only to print it. The problem is to get the arguments to be used as commands. E.g. passing `"echo firstecho" "echo secondecho"` would output "firstecho", followed by a newline, and then "secondecho."

Comment: That's a completely different interface, where you have each command passed as a pre-escaped/pre-quoted string -- and it's a harder one to use safely, because it means someone has to use `printf '%q'` or an equivalent to safely form each individual argument in the first place, or have those arguments be hand-generated and hand-audited by humans with no literal substitution of data into them. Taking each word in a simple shell command as a single argument and executing that command list literally is that it's safe from shell injection attacks; what you're proposing above is not.