# Execute two programs in separate screen windows with bash

Tags: bash

I’ve been toying around to create a functional bash script to solve my problem, but have’t been successful.

**The problem:**

I need to execute these two scripts from different terminals (or windows using `screen`):

```
fluidsynth -a alsa -c 3 -g 3 /usr/share/sound/sf2/piano.sf2
```

```
aconnect 20:0 128:0
```

What I would do manually is launch `screen` and execute the first command then `ctrl+a+c` and execute the second.

**The important part:**

The second command can only be run after the `fluidsynth` programs successfully powers-up, and must be run from a different terminal.

**My attempt so far:**

```
screen -S fluid /usr/midi/fluid.sh & sleep 10 aconnect 20:0 128:0
```

The fluid.sh file:

```
fluidsynth -a alsa -c 3 -g 3 /usr/share/sound/sf2/piano.sf2
```

Could anyone point out what I’m doing wrong here?

Comment: You may find this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239264/bash-execute-command-with-arguments-in-new-terminal

Comment: Thanks, but I want my script to depend on `screen` not gnome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer would be:

```
screen -d -m -S fluid fluidsynth -a alsa -c 3 -g 3 /usr/share/sound/sf2/piano.sf2
screen -d -m -S connect bash -c "sleep 10; aconnect 20:0 128:0"
```

`-d -m` tells screen to start in detached mode.

If you have a way to detect fluidsynth's powerup, e.g. there's a file that should be there, you can replace the `sleep 10` with a loops that does `sleep 1` until the file exists.